# Templated class definition does not compile in VS2017

Tags: c++, templates

I have this class definition (simplified here) which compiled fine with VS2008. In VS2017, I get a syntax error C2059 on the first angle bracket:

```
template < typename Function, typename Base, typename Specialiser = Base >
class FunctionTermBase : public Base
{
public:
    // typedef typename Function::result_type result_type;
    typedef typename Base term_type;
    typedef typename Specialiser specialiser;

protected:
    FunctionTermBase() { }

public:
    template <typename T>
    struct Specialise {
        typedef typename specialiser::Specialise<T>::type type;
    };
};
```

I'd appreciate if someone could tell me what is wrong with this code?

Comment: ***I get a syntax error C2059 on the first angle bracket:*** It may help to add the text of the exact error message to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use the [`template`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/template) keyword to indicate that the following dependent name also has template arguments. Additionally, `typename` is not required in your `typedef`s since the identifiers are already known to be types (they are template arguments).

```
template < typename Function, typename Base, typename Specialiser = Base >
class FunctionTermBase : public Base
{
public:
    // typedef typename Function::result_type result_type;
    typedef Base term_type;
    typedef Specialiser specialiser;

protected:
    FunctionTermBase() { }

public:
    template <typename T>
    struct Specialise {
        typedef typename specialiser::template Specialise<T>::type type;
        //          Add template here ^^^^^^^^
    };
};
```